# Firebase - Add displayName to Authentication User without code

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating an app for a client working in advertising for artists.
This app consists in a dashboard supposed to display several informations plus the artist's name.

I'm using Firebase to provide my client a simple interface to add the artists accounts to a database, but I would like him to set their name, ideally without implementing a back-office.

Is there any way to add a displayName to a Firebase Auth User without code, hence directly with the website interface ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't way to change user's `displayName` in Firebase Auth object and only the user can change their name using the client SDK. You would have to use Admin SDK using Cloud functions or a server to do that.

You can however update the name in database and make sure the user trying to update the name is authorized by using [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) or storing their UID in database and checking that in security rules.

---

One hack would be to check if user's name in database matches the name in Firebase Auth object. If not, run a function which will update it.